# THREE.js Orbit controls zooming limits

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I am using Orbit controls and they have a weird limit.

Zooming depends on the radius of the spherical coordinates of the camera relative to the orbiting axis. I'll try to explain how it works:

Everytime the user scrolls, the value of `scale` changes in this magnitude:

(if the user zooms in)

`scale *= Math.pow(0.95, scope.zoomSpeed)`

(or if user zooms out)

`scale /= Math.pow(0.95, scope.zoomSpeed)`

Then, the radius value changes with each update like this:
`spherical.radius *= scale`

Then the scale value is reassigned its default value
`scale = 1`
so the radius won't change with each update

The value of `spherical.radius` is what determines how close you are at what the camera is looking at so, of course, you have a limit when zooming in because the radius can only get so little (see that zooming in multiplies the radius value by .95, so it gets closer to 0 everytime)

The problem is if you zoom close to the orbiting axis (`spherical.radius` ~= 0), then rotate the camera and look down (or up or wherever) you can’t zoom into that direction because `spherical.radius` can't be any smaller!

So, my question is, how can I achieve that behavior (zooming up or down when the radius is at its limit) using Orbit controls.

P.S. This code can be found in `OrbitControl.js` of the `THREE.js` library, more specifically in the `this.update()` function. Here's the [github repo](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L125)

Comment: are you talking about minzoom? please do share your code! question is not self-explanatory!

Comment: no, I'm not talking about the minzoom and there's actually no code of mine to add, I'm not doing anything particular, I could add a fiddle of the basic use of the controls. If you zoom in enough (with minzoom = 0 as default), zooming will get slower until you cant zoom, if you rotate the camera you'll still won't be able to zoom, regardless of the direction you are lookingAt

Comment: @UllasHunka the `OrbitControls` names are randomly assigned. Zoom doesn't have anything to do with actual zooming. Imagine i had a restaurant but instead of calling my dishes `steak` or `stew` i called them `picture frame` or `car wheel`. The question sounds confusing because of this i believe. But i think it's valid.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve this thanks to [pailhead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2548153/pailhead) (thanks again!)

Added the following to the `this.update()` function in `OrbitControls.js`

To get the vector where the camera is looking at

```
var cameraWorldDir = new THREE.Vector3();
scope.object.getWorldDirection(cameraWorldDir);
```

Magic:

```
if (spherical.radius <= 2) {
    scope.target.add(cameraWorldDir.multiplyScalar(0.4));
}
```

So, if I ever get close enough to the center, I just move the target (orbiting center) along the lookAt vector, aka I push it back.

See the full thread in the threejs forum [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/orbit-controls-zooming-limits/3148/12)

Comment: In my experience you also should add some length(lower than to scope.target) to the <code>spherical.radius</code>. In other way your <code>spherical.radius</code> with every scroll will strive to zero. After it has reached <=2 it will never have returned back to bigger values. And with it you will be able to avoid a bug when your camera is moving during rotating.

Comment: I found a better solution, after changing `scope.target` simple divide `spherical.radius` by `scale`. Well, at least it works for me, maybe someone will find it useful too.

Answer (score 2):

You might be confused by the terminology used in `OrbitControls`

What "zoom" refers to is called "dolly" in the real world. It's a device used to create camera movements:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_dolly

In the real world, "zooming a camera" means something different:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zooming_(filmmaking)

It requires changing the focal length of the lens to make the field of view narrower or wider (how much of the world you capture on screen from the same vantage point).

When you hit the `minZoom` value, you haven't actually done any zooming, you've got as close as you can to your orbit center.

You could try to disable the "zoom" or dolly on the `OrbitControls` and try to implement your own controller for just changing the `camera.fov` (zoom).